# I cant seem to get the right answer . Find a unit vector that is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$, $u=(-8,-6,4)$, $v=(10,-12,-2)$

Tags: calculus

I cant seem to get the right answer,  it's like I'm missing something.  Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Take the cross product

Comment: I did but still can't

Comment: Convert it to a unit vector by finding the norm..

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$w=u\times v$$

Is a vector orthogonal to both, $u$ and $v$.

So, you are looking for

$$\frac{w}{|w|}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(-8,-6,4)\times (10,-12,-2)=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\-8&-6&4\\10&-12&-2\end{vmatrix}=(60,24,156)=12(5,2,13)$$

and now just evaluate $\;\left\|(60,24,156)\right\|=12\sqrt{25+4+169}\;$ and ...

Answer (score 1):

Take the cross product of $u$ and $v$; this produces a vector, almost certainly not of unit length. You then need to find a unit vector pointing in the same direction.

Given a vector (for example, $(1, 2, 3)$), to obtain the unit vector in the same direction, you just need to divide by the length. In the case of $(1, 2, 3)$, the length is $\sqrt{14}$, so the unit vector is $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}})$.